# VirtualBox Set Hostname and Domain name via DHCP Server

Tags: virtualbox, dhcp

I try to create NAT Network which all VM machines are assigned hostname and IP addresses by DHCP. According to my quick research, I can assign IP address with following command and I see option about domain name and hostname in helper page but there is not usage example:

```bash
VBoxManage dhcpserver modify --netname NatNetwork --mac-address=080027D23E28 --fixed-address=10.13.13.254
```

This is the helper page piece

```bash
[root@localhost~]# VBoxManage dhcpserver modify --help | grep -i hostname -A 2
    12 - HostName
        The client name. See RFC 1035 for character limits.
```

Could you give me example of command for set hostname option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hostname is published by the operating system that is running within
the VM. It's not dictated by VirtualBox.

The specific command for changing the hostname depends on the
operating system installed in the VM.

Comment: We can configure dhcp-client hostname with dhcp-server (`option host-name "hostname"`) side statements. I try it before it's work. Why I can't configure VBoxManage?

Comment: "option host-name" is useless - see [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144847/what-is-the-option-host-name-for-in-etc-dhcp-dhcpd-conf).

Comment: Ok, I try to set up OCP Cluster with custom network. I set up DHCP and DNS services and all RHCOS nodes take IP address and it's hostname but this cluster have not access to internet. So set up process is interrupted. I aim that all nodes access to internet. And than other way i need custom DHCP server. How Should I design network infrastructure on virtual box?

Comment: This would be better in a separate question with full details of the desired network. My answer here is only about this one limited question.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for quick response. I asked new question. I will appreciate if you help me...